# How to properly kpm cache clean?

Tags: asp.net, macos, asp.net-core, kpm

I'm trying to use [ASP.NET 5](https://github.com/aspnet/Home) and their new command line tools (`kpm`, `kvm`, etc) on my Mac (OSX 10.10.1) but I'm having problems with `kpm install`. The install generally works fine, except when a new version of a package was just published, `kpm` says it is unable to locate the package, e.g.:

```
~/Projects/myproj: kpm install My.Custom.Pkg 1.0.4
  CACHE https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?Id='My.Custom.Pkg'
  CACHE https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?Id='My.Custom.Pkg'
  CACHE http://tools.production.com/nuget/FindPackagesById()?Id='My.Custom.Pkg'
My.Custom.Pkg.1.0.4 was added to project.json.
Restoring packages for /Users/montgomeryc/Projects/myproj/project.json
  CACHE https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?Id='My.Custom.Pkg'
  CACHE https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?Id='My.Custom.Pkg'
  CACHE http://tools.production.com/nuget/FindPackagesById()?Id='My.Custom.Pkg'
Resolving complete, 4286ms elapsed
Unable to locate My.Custom.Pkg >= 1.0.4
Restore complete, 4294ms elapsed
```

If I wait about 20 minutes and `kpm install My.Custom.Pkg 1.0.4` again, it will find the new package version. This seems to be a problem with the `kpm` cache because I can open up Visual Studio on my Windows machine and find the newly published package instantly.

My question is: **is there a way to forcefully clear the local kpm cache?** And not the `~/.kpm/packages` directory either... that doesn't seem to help this use case. There seems to be another internal http cache when it's making the GET request to the various NuGet feeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `--no-cache` argument for `kpm install`:

```
kpm install --no-cache My.Custom.Pkg 1.0.4
```

Comment: That did it, thanks! Wish `kpm` had a way to "clean" the cache like `npm` does via its `npm cache clean`